# I am getting Runtime Error - SIGSEGV when i submit it

Tags: c++, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am new to graphs and just started practicing bfs.
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/tutorial/

when i compile my problem it runs without a problem but when i submit it, it throws error.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;


class Graph{
    int V;
    list<int>*adj;

    public:
    Graph(int v);
    void addedge(int u,int v);
    void bfs(int s);

};

Graph::Graph(int v)
{
    this->V=v;
    adj=new list<int>[v];
};

void Graph:: addedge(int u,int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);
    adj[v].push_back(u);
}

void Graph:: bfs(int s)
{
bool *visited=new bool[V];

   for(int i=0;i<V;i++)
       visited[i]=false;

   list<int>queue;
   visited[1]=true;

   int temp;
   queue.push_back(1);

   int curr_level=1;

   list<int>::iterator i;

   int counter=1;
   //int flag=0;
   int result=0;
   int count=0;
   while(!queue.empty())
   {
     temp=queue.front();
     queue.pop_front();
     counter--;


     for(i=adj[temp].begin();i!=adj[temp].end();++i)
     {
        if(!visited[*i])
        {
            visited[*i]=true;
            queue.push_back(*i);
        }
        count++;
     }


  if(counter>=0)
  {
    result+=count;
    count=0;
  }
  if(counter==0)
  {
     curr_level++;
     counter=result;
  }

  if(curr_level==s)
  {
    break;
   }

  }
  cout<<result<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    Graph g(n);
    int x,y;
    n--;
    while(n--)
    {
      cin>>x>>y;
      g.addedge(x,y);
     }
     int p;
     cin>>p;
     if(p==1)
        return 1;
     else
        g.bfs(p);
}
```

Comment: Sigsegv occurs due to allocation or accessing memory in wrong way. You must be iterating out of allocated space in one of the loops

Comment: but i don't think that is possible here coz i am using stl iterator here and it can not possibly go out of bounds.

Comment: If I see it right, your program crashes already for the sample input. So take it from here and use debugger.

Comment: no it is running perfectly fine for the sample input..

Comment: it shows accepted when i click on compile and test if that is what u mean by sample input

Comment: error free Compilation and segmentation fault are unrelated. SIGSEGV is a runtime error